# How can I do VPN on Hughes HT2010, do I need to open port 500?

Tags: vpn

I am trying to do VPN on a VSAT link using Hughes Jupiter 2010 but it is not working. Do I need to open port 500? And how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you should add the VPN protocol?